# How to hide items in the correct sequence? , Using waypoint, TweenMax, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I'm collapsando the header when I scroll the browser window, I'm using waypoints to trigger a function when passing a certain limit.

My problem is how to do that, for example, when I scroll down first disappear content (form inputs) and then change the height of the header, and then when I scroll up first increase height and then display the contents (form inputs) .

How do you could do?

I have a example here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gonzalo2683/fz46ray5/3/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init(){

    var header, pageContainer, pageContent, brandImage;

    header = $('header');
    pageContainer = $('#page-container');
    pageContent = $('#page-content');
    brandImage = $('.brand img');

    //functions
    collapseHaeder();


    function collapseHaeder(){
        if(pageContainer.hasClass('collapse-header')){
            var waypoint = new Waypoint({
                element: document.getElementById('page-content'),
                handler: function(direction) {

                    var elementsToResize = $('header, .brand-holder, .header-content');
                    var hideElms = $('.hide-element');

                    if(direction == 'up'){
                        hideElements(hideElms);
                        resizeHeader(elementsToResize);
                    }else {
                        resizeHeader(elementsToResize);
                        hideElements(hideElms);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }


    function resizeHeader(elemts){
        var newHeight = 45;
        var brandHeight = newHeight - 10;
        var easingEffect = 'Quart.easeInOut';

        if(!elemts.hasClass('resized')){
            elemts.addClass('resized');

        }else {
            elemts.removeClass('resized');
            newHeight = 140;
            brandHeight = newHeight / 2;
        }
        //header elements  containers
        TweenMax.to(elemts, 1, {height:newHeight, ease: easingEffect});
        //page container padding
        TweenMax.to(pageContainer, 1, {paddingTop:newHeight, ease: easingEffect});
        //brand image
        TweenMax.to(brandImage, 1, {height:brandHeight, ease: easingEffect});
    }

    function hideElements(hiddenElement){
        var classHidded = 'has-hided';
        if(!hiddenElement.hasClass(classHidded)){
            hiddenElement.addClass(classHidded);
            hiddenElement.fadeOut(800);
        }else {
            hiddenElement.fadeIn(500);
            hiddenElement.removeClass(classHidded);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You want to use a callback function with tweenMax. And also callback functions with jQuery functions. They will make your code synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` when you are already using **GSAP**. Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/y2nt83dn/) that I have created, code of which is as follows:

```
/*global TweenMax,TimelineMax*/
$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
    var header, pageContainer, pageContent, brandImage, brandHolder, headerContent, hideElement;
    var duration = .8,
        ease = 'Power4.easeInOut',
        stagger = duration * .2;
    var minHeight = 45;
    var brandHeight = minHeight - 10;
    var classNameResized = 'resized';
    var classNameHidden = 'has-hided';
    var fadeTween = null,
        heightTween = null,
        paddingTween = null,
        imageTween = null;
    header = $('header');
    pageContainer = $('#page-container');
    pageContent = $('#page-content');
    brandImage = $('.brand img');
    brandHolder = $('.brand-holder');
    headerContent = $('.header-content');
    hideElement = $('.hide-element');
    //functions
    initTweens();
    collapseHaeder();

    function initTweens() {
        fadeTween = TweenMax.to(hideElement, duration, {
            autoAlpha: 0,
            display: 'none',
            ease: ease,
            paused: true
        });
        heightTween = TweenMax.to([header, brandHolder, headerContent], duration, {
            height: minHeight,
            ease: ease,
            paused: true,
            delay: stagger
        });
        paddingTween = TweenMax.to(pageContainer, duration, {
            paddingTop: minHeight,
            ease: ease,
            paused: true,
            delay: stagger
        });
        imageTween = TweenMax.to(brandImage, duration, {
            height: brandHeight,
            ease: ease,
            paused: true,
            delay: stagger
        });
    }

    function addClasses() {
        if (!header.hasClass(classNameResized)) {
            header.addClass(classNameResized);
            brandHolder.addClass(classNameResized);
            headerContent.addClass(classNameResized);
        }
        if (!hideElement.hasClass(classNameHidden)) {
            hideElement.addClass(classNameHidden);
        }
    }

    function removeClasses() {
        if (header.hasClass(classNameResized)) {
            header.removeClass(classNameResized);
            brandHolder.removeClass(classNameResized);
            headerContent.removeClass(classNameResized);
        }
        if (hideElement.hasClass(classNameHidden)) {
            hideElement.removeClass(classNameHidden);
        }
    }

    function collapseHaeder() {
        if (pageContainer.hasClass('collapse-header')) {
            var waypoint = new Waypoint({
                element: pageContent,
                handler: function (direction) {
                    if (direction == 'up') {
                        fadeTween.reverse();
                        heightTween.reverse();
                        paddingTween.reverse();
                        imageTween.reverse();
                        removeClasses();
                    } else {
                        fadeTween.play();
                        heightTween.play();
                        paddingTween.play();
                        imageTween.play();
                        addClasses();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

There are many things that can be improved here in terms of code structure, animation style etc e.g. animating `translateY` instead of `height` for a more smooth animation ([Link](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) & [Link](https://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/)) but I have tried to keep the structure / approach of the code untouched.

Hope it helps.

P.S. I would strongly recommend to take a look at [TimelineMax](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/) as well for all your sequencing needs in animations. I have also forked [another version](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/qfsg7Lyt/) using **TimelineMax**.

T

Comment: Thanks, it works great, one more question. In this case it is better to use TweenMax or TimelineMax?

Comment: Since what you are trying to achieve is relatively simple, I think `TweenMax` is sufficient enough. Adding `TimelineMax` to this would mean adding more kilobytes to the page. But for advanced sequencing needs in future, `TimelineMax` is the way to go. Here is a [great resource](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/series/the-beginners-guide-to-timelinemax--cms-765) for you to understand all about it.

Comment: Hello @tahir-ahmed , another little question. In the following [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Gonzalo2683/0veqxee1/), i have the same sample, but in the line 84 a create a variable to get the height of the header, when the header is collapse the console show me 140px, but when is open show me 45. Why?. Another thing, whe i have a no much content, tweenmax try to collapse but bring back to the initial state immediately. Thanks

Comment: hey @chalo, re `heightHeader` I am guessing are you expecting to see the results reversed?

Comment: So is, in little unusual to have a small element and having a large dimension and vice versa.

I need also adjust other elementos based on the height of the header and when I get up I returns the value inversely.

Comment: `heighHeader` displays **140px** value when **collapsed** because `heightHeader` is calculated *before* the animation (i.e. the collapsing animation) has finished. Infact, the value is calculated when the animation has not even begun.

Comment: `onComplete` & `onReverseComplete` callbacks should help. [[Link](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/)]

Comment: @chalo: would just like to clarify something I said earlier, `TimelineMax` does **not** add extra kilobytes if you are already using`TweenMax` because `TweenMax` already [comes equipped](https://ihatetomatoes.net/greensock-cheat-sheet/) with `TimelineMax`. I apologize.